# Barplot with paneldata

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, panel-data

I'm struggling quiet a lot to make a barplot showing me, how many observations in each category of `voted`

The thing is. I have a "voted" variable in my panel dataframe, numeric which is telling me, which party one voted for in 2012 and 2014.

Here is a reproducible example

```
id <- c('1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3')
wave <- c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2014)
voted <- c(1, NA, 4, 1, NA, 2, 2, NA, 4)
mydata <- data.frame(id, wave, voted)
```

There has only been election in 2012 and 2014 - and therefore the NA's. Each number stands for a name of the party.

I want to show in a barplot how many respondents voted for party 1, 2, 4...

I've tried the following:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = as.factor(voted), y = year, fill = year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

However as you might see, it looks really weird.

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ffhi.jpg)

Im more interested in something like this:

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyQra.jpg)

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a barplot the y value is the height of the bar which I think is "voted" in your request and the x value is the categories, probably "id" and the subcategories probably "year". I don't think you want to make the y value a factor. Furthermore "year" is not a column name and you are missing a parenthesis in the ggplot call. (You should have gotten and error with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(wave) %>% 
  count(voted) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(voted), n, fill=factor(wave)))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I need to remove a factor level - eg number 4. Is it possible to filter on each level in the factor(voted) variable? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is an illustration of applying the issues I identified in the comment above:

> In a barplot the y value is the height of the bar which I think is "voted" in your request and the x value is the categories, probably "id" and the subcategories probably "year". I don't think you want to make the y value a factor. Furthermore "year" is not a column name and you are missing a parenthesis in the ggplot call. (You should have gotten and error with that code. –

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = id, y = voted, fill = factor(wave))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
#Warning message:
#Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]